# Cannot install ubuntu 14.10 from usb.(Wn-block(2,0) trace)

Tags: system-installation

I have a dual boot lenovo G510 laptop. It has windows 7 and edubuntu atm.(Couldn't get ubuntu 13 to work back when I got the laptop) .
Now I want to try out the latest ubuntu.But when I try to install it from a USB, if I click on try without installing or Install ubuntu option I get a black screem with wn-block(2,0) and some values.I'am very new to linux .
My wifi in edubuntu is also not getting detected(same works fine on windows). 
So I really need a proper working ubuntu.Please help me with this. 
Thank you
Regards,
Kai.